# How to restore scroll position of refreshed div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, get

I have a very large div which makes the page have scrollbars vertically and horizontally.

Every few minutes, I want the div's content to be refreshed, so I use jquery get to reload the div contents into the div.

The catch is that I don't want the place on the screen that the user was looking at to be changed, I want the div to reload, but the user should still be looking at the same spot in the div (meaning the div should not scroll back to (0,0).

What sometimes happens when overwriting the html into the div with $( "#mainwrapper" ).html( data );, the div is momentarily empty, so it shrinks, and then is refilled, but the user is now at (0,0)

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point in keeping the scroll position if the entire contents changed..? BTW, So the `<div>` is having auto `height`and `width`..?

Comment: I keep the position because the div contents are to be refreshed to change for changes in the content since the user loaded the page. The user doesnt want to jump back to the corner.

Comment: the div is a set width and height, the content inside can be long and wide and thus #mainwrapper has scrollbars

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before you load the content into the div, save the scroll position.

```
var scroll_l = $('#yourdiv').scrollLeft(),
  scroll_t = $('#yourdiv').scrollTop();
```

Each time you scroll the div, save the position sothat scrolling while loading gets saved, too.

```
$('#yourdiv').scroll(function() {
  if ($('#yourdiv').html().length) {
    scroll_l = $('#yourdiv').scrollLeft();
    scroll_t = $('#yourdiv').scrollTop();
  }
});
```

And then, load the new content and re-apply the scroll positions:

```
$('#yourdiv').load('/your/url', function() {
  $('#yourdiv').scrollLeft(scroll_l);
  $('#yourdiv').scrollTop(scroll_t);
});
```