# How to restore scroll position after ajax image loading in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have a small piece of JavaScript which is delivered with an dynamic image.
The image is re-rendered by the server and refreshed via ajax on each click. I want to restore the scollposition after each reload of the image. 
The JavaScript I use is a modification of the accepted answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015090/):

```
$img.load(function() { 
  var scrollElement = document.getElementById(SCROLL_ID);
  if(scrollElement) {
    scrollElement.scrollTop = jQuery.data(scrollElement, "yPos");
    scrollElement.scrollLeft = jQuery.data(scrollElement, "xPos");
  };
});
```

It works fine with IE 8 and FF 37. Now I have to Support IE 11, which causes some problems. Though the function is evaluated after each reload, it seems is is evaluated *before* the Image is rendered by the browser, so the scroller is not yet visible.

Any help is appreciated.

*Edit:* The page is running in document mode 8.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `scrollElement.scrollTo(0,0)`

Comment: ScrollTo(x,y) seems not to be supported. The problem is not setting the scrollposition, but to fire the function after the Image is inserted.